# JS wont update placeholder in dom

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, placeholder

JS wont update the placeholder after giving it a value

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="B" readonly>
```

JS (buttonpres)

```
a=Sander 
document.getElementById("B").placeholder=a;
```

after

HTML
Website stil has

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="B" readonly>`

Wen logging to console

`(<input type="text" class="form-control" id="B" placeholder="Sander" readonly>);`

it show the update code. but wen inspecting the DOM it still shows the old code. tried many things but i cant for the life of my get it to work

Comment: I just tried and it worked. Could you please provide a working example where the issue is reproduced? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
function setPlaceholder() {

  let a = 'Sander'
  document.getElementById("B").setAttribute('placeholder', a);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="B" readonly>
<button type='button' onclick='setPlaceholder()'>Set Placeholder</button>
```

Comment: This obviously works but just setting  the `placeholder` attribute should work too, I'd think.

Comment: ... and yes indeed the property on the element works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all i just found out i just the same id 2 times in my code
So i hat two ids whit "B"

Comment: This must be a comment or edit the Question and add as an update.